# WPF Check the window availability in different UI thread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I had created a new window in a new thread as following:

```
private WindowNew windowNew;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));
        windowNew = new WindowNew();
        windowNew.Show();
        windowNew.Closed += (s, e) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    newWindowThread.Start();
}
```

How can I check the instance availability of windowNew?

Comment: I think the answer will be, "don't do this".  Why have you decided to create a new thread to open a new window?  If there is some process within that window that takes time, THEN create a thread.

Comment: According to the sample code, windowNew contains a camera view that update UI rapidly. If I have only on UI thread, some operation will be blocked by the view update.

Or any other better solution for my case?

Comment: If the new windows is exist, I will not create it again.

Comment: Generally, you only want one thread to update all parts of the UI.  I doubt the camera will be updating so fast that the main UI thread won't be able to keep up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
if(windowNew!=null) return;
...
 windowNew.Closed += (s, e) => 
{
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
windowNew = null;
}
}
```

Also you have to care about the synchronization(if statement and Closed event handler)